# Solr highlighting through Scorched in Django

Tags: python, django, solr, sunburnt

I am trying to output the highlighted search-term from a Solr search. I'm using Django 1.8.4 with Scorched.

I have already activated highlighting `(resp = ('highlighting', self.solr_response.highlighting))` and to the search-view, and my json output from a search is:

```
"highlighting": {

"f0109b89-4882-44cc-90b2-6a51561d14ee": { }, <!-- nothing here, though the result comes up)
"73bc1fe4-2c4a-4036-9373-242811e3e7d9": { },<!-- nothing here, though the result comes up)
"b7e7a44a-57c4-4378-94fc-273229b0ac7f":
{
"some_field":
[
    "Bla bla bla, <em>highlighted search-term</em> bla bla bla..."
]
},
)
```

The problem is that I cannot find the way how to tell the Django template system to access that `some_field`, since it's under `content.highlighting` (and its id is under `result.id`). Of course `content.highlighting.result.id.some_field` doesn't work - is there a way of concatenating something like `{{ content.highlighting}} + {{ result.id }}`, so that I can output the highlighted string in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this is how I solved my problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/python-sunburnt/-5o4_omo03U/1SSGAyoZghoJ).

Basically, I added this code in the view:

```
for d in response:
    d['highlighted_string'] = response.highlighting[d['id']]
results_list = response
```

so that each result-item coming from solr contains the highlighted_string corresponding to its own ID. Then, in the template, result.highlighted_string outputs the correct highlighted_string corresponding with that result.

I hope it can be of help to someone else.